# Resize multiple images in a folder (Python)

Tags: python, resize, python-imaging-library

I already saw the examples suggested but some of them don't work.

So, I have this code which seems to work fine for one image:

```
im = Image.open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Images\\2.jpg') # image extension *.png,*.jpg
new_width  = 1200
new_height = 750
im = im.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\resized.tif') # .jpg is deprecated and raise error....
```

How can I iterate it and resize more than one image ? Aspect ration need to be maintained.

Thank you

Comment: what do you want to iterate over? images in a folder?

Comment: Yes..All the images in that folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to iterate over images in a specific folder.

You can do this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

for image_file_name in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Images\\'):
    if image_file_name.endswith(".tif"):
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f')

        im = Image.open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Images\\'+image_file_name)
        new_width  = 1282
        new_height = 797
        im = im.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im.save('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test_resize\\resized' + now + '.tif')
```

`datetime.now()` is just added to make the image names unique. It is just a hack that came to my mind first. You can do something else. This is needed in order not to override each other.

Comment: the code give error because it can't find the image...Ok, because in the first line any is specified. It should be an extension (*.jpg), right ?

Comment: Don't work.. It gives me 'No such file or directory: '12.tif'.....which is strange because this file exist in the the folder

Comment: It should not try to resize `.tif` files. It should only work with `.jpg`. Also, it may be the permission issue

Comment: I tried to do with a .jpg but nothing..Can you try it for yourself ? It works for you ? The code I posted work fine with .tif files..

Comment: @BlueTrack see my updated answer. Looks like you need an absolute url of the image. Because relative url will change depending on where you execute your  script

Comment: LOL, I added the same line in im.save.
I made it work. There is something wrong with datetime.now()..I will edit your answer..
Thank you very much.

Comment: @BlueTrack great. Also consider accepting it as well if it helped

Comment: Hi @JahongirRahmonov ,
How would you take your input image name as a output file name instead of date&time ?

Answer (score 3):

```
# Resize all images in a directory to half the size.
#
# Save on a new file with the same name but with "small_" prefix
# on high quality jpeg format.
#
# If the script is in /images/ and the files are in /images/2012-1-1-pics
# call with: python resize.py 2012-1-1-pics

import Image
import os
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
print("Processing %s" % file_name)
image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory, file_name))

x,y = image.size
new_dimensions = (x/2, y/2) #dimension set here
output = image.resize(new_dimensions, Image.ANTIALIAS)

output_file_name = os.path.join(directory, "small_" + file_name)
output.save(output_file_name, "JPEG", quality = 95)

print("All done")
```

Where it says

```
new_dimensions = (x/2, y/2)
```

You can set any dimension value you want
for example, if you want 300x300, then change the code like the code line below

```
new_dimensions = (300, 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a list of images in some folder and you to resize all of them

```
from PIL import Image
import os

    source_folder = 'path/to/where/your/images/are/located/'
    destination_folder = 'path/to/where/you/want/to/save/your/images/after/resizing/'
    directory = os.listdir(source_folder)
    
    for item in directory:
        img = Image.open(source_folder + item)
        imgResize = img.resize((new_image_width, new_image_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imgResize.save(destination_folder + item[:-4] +'.tif', quality = 90)
```